# when to apply feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am developing a software used to automate machine learning .

I have observed in some of the datasets with less number of  features (4,5),if we apply feature selection and consequently my classifiers models the performance actually decreases(due to the loss of information)... But in cases of datasets with larger number of features if we apply feature selection the performance actually improves....... 
So I am looking for some heurestic so as to determine whether to apply feature selection or not ?
Is there any paper /work which addresses this issue ?When to apply feature selection and when not to ?

Comment: Why not apply machine learning to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few heuristics.  I don't know a single paper or source that addresses them all in a trivial amount of time.

When you say 'performance' I'm assuming you're referring to the accuracy of prediction for your test data set by your model which has been trained and cross validated by a training data set and cross validation data set.

There are a large number of ML algorithms as well, feature selection may not affect them all the same.  Which are you using?

For example Applying  feature selection for a Neural Network will result in changes that affect the Bias and Variance of you model which in turn will affect the accuracy of prediction on the test set:

- too many features may result in overfitting (depending on sample training size) due to high varience
- too few you may end up underfitting or high bias (regardless of sample training size)

Either will cause prediction on test sets to suffer. Also, accuracy alone isn't enough when 'tuning' a models (figuring out feature, degrees, regularization lambda's, etc...) To figure out what's best what you'll need to look at is the precision and recall of your model.

Unfortunately, there's no quick-and-easy way I can explain in a short SO answer in detail what you need to do to optimize your model.

I suggest you spend the time to take something like Andrew Ng's intro to machine learning course https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/welcome.  Chapter 6 discusses how to determine how to optimize NN model.